# Word/phrase for negative side effect(s)

Tags: meaning, single-word-requests, phrase-requests

In an essay I want to enumerate and describe negative aspects of using a popular and working tool. Since such issues are usually overlooked (or even underestimated), I call them negative side effects. Now, I'm looking for a better (preferably single) word/phrase to describe those **negative side effects**, something other than *drawback* or *disadvantage*.

Comment: Why don't you want to use _drawback_ or _disadvantage_ (or presumably _downside_, which is the one I'd have chosen)? Understanding why those words don't quite work for you might help find the one which does.

Comment: I want to put those negative side effects in a category besides other problems. For example, I have three categories for problems with the tool: Technical problems, Managerial problems and  negative side effects. So, using disadvantages or drawbacks instead of negative side effects seem to be misleading.

Comment: Hmm - I'm afraid I still don't understand what separates these from the other categories of problem you mention.  For example, how does a "negative side effect" differ from a "technical problem"?  Perhaps an example would help (though I appreciate it might be difficult to give a simple enough example if there's a lot of prior knowledge involved).

Comment: Eilia - everyone is telling you the same thing!  Heh!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> Any adverse and [**unwanted effect**](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/fallout)/: a bad effect or result of
>   something :
>   **[fallout](http://www.vocabulary.com/dictionary/fallout)**
>
> A phenomenon that follows and is caused by some previous phenomenon:
>   **upshot**-

- Do not confuse "Upshot" with "upside," which is exclusively positive.
- **Though the "up" metaphor may lead you to think of a positive
  connotation, the word is often used for negative effects.**

Comment: +1 for fallout. But `upshot` is _not_ the same thing as a side-effect. And it cannot be used in plural. You've been warned. `Fallout` is a mass noun, so it might be passable.

Comment: @TusharRaj, you are confusing me. Why can't it be "upshots
".  ( "But one of the upshots is that publishers have now firmly accepted the principle that ebooks should be cheaper than their physical counterparts").

Comment: [Oxford Dictionaries](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/upshot) says (I think) that it can only be used in the singular; other dictionaries don't.  The plural does sound a little contrived though.  The normal reason to use "upshot" is to signal that you're netting a complex situation down to a single conclusion - so acknowledging that there's more than one conclusion is slightly counter to the way the word's generally used in practice.

Comment: A synonym for fallout in some situations is *collateral damage*.

Answer (score 3):

[Disbenefits](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/disbenefit?q=disbenefits) is a word I have used from time to time, though I was astonished to find that it doesn't appear in all dictionaries so may be office-speak, slang or new and is designated as 'British [English]' in the site linked in this answer

> Disbenefit
>
> **Noun**: A disadvantage or loss resulting from something:
>    ‘an environmental disbenefit to the area of Teesside’
>
> *www.oxforddictionaries.com*

Answer (score 1):

If you think these side effects are tricky, or perhaps not particularly obvious from the outset, then colloquially you might say these are 'gotchas'.

[Merriam-Webster defines 'gotcha'](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/gotcha) as, "an unexpected problem or usually unpleasant surprise".

For example:

> Newcomers often use PHP due to the prevalence of tutorials, but the gotchas can make finishing more complex projects very difficult.

Answer (score 0):

Try **[by-products](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/by-product?q=byproducts)**

> An unintended but inevitable secondary result:
>
> *he saw poverty as the by-product of colonial prosperity*

Answer (score 0):

Google search:
weakness, imperfection, handicap, limitation, trouble, difficulty, problem, complication; hindrance, obstacle, impediment, obstruction, inconvenience, discouragement, deterrent, disadvantage, 
Any of these should work.